# What are people in big groups who move a lot called?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

Are people who move a lot in groups called settlers?

I don't know what else; I'm doing an report on native Americans and the Wyandotte culture. They move in big groups I don't know what that's called but I really need to know.

Comment: People who settle are called settlers.

Comment: "they call me the **wanderer**, yeah the wanderer.."

Comment: Seems like an answer depends on why the group moves a lot. Armies move a lot.  Parties (hunting and otherwise) can move a lot. Nomads (below) move a lot (best one yet).  I don't think there is something general.  Great question.

Comment: They would probably be described in a number of different ways, depending on the exact context. Can you provide an example sentence or few?

Comment: What kind of "movement" are you talking about? Moving around in one place"? A large crowd going the same direction? A community migrating together? You have nowhere near enough detail here for us to give you a good answer.

Comment: Shifting cultivators? (If they do that)

Answer (score 27):

This might be a group of nomads.

[Nomad](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/nomad)

> A member of a people that travels from place to place to find fresh pasture for its animals and has no permanent home:
>   *‘the withering of their grasslands forced the nomads of the Sahara to descend into the Nile valley’*

Reference:
https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/nomad

Comment: +1 or _Beduins_, _Gypsies_.

Comment: @NVZ thanks. Of course not all nomads are Bedouins, gypsies, and not even all Bedouins & gypsies are nomads any more these days, having settled down...

Comment: True that. The times they are a-changing.

Comment: Don't you mean "a nomadic group" rather than "a group of nomads"?

Answer (score 6):

[Wyandotte](http://www.wyandotte-nation.org/culture/history/) people were forced to move due to conflict with other tribes (including the largest tribe of all, the US government.)

They eventually [**settled**](https://www.google.com/search?q=settlers%20meaning&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b&gfe_rd=cr&ei=bDqjWJTVAvGw8wfX9YvQDQ) in one place, and formed a nation. So they were settlers in a sense.

However, to arrive there they **migrated**.

Although the word has a recent connotation equating it with refugee, or even farm worker,

[**Migrant**](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/migrant) is

> a person that travels to a different country or place, often in order to find work

-Cambridge on-line

The word can also be used to refer to a type of seasonal behaviour, such as the what the [Sioux Plains Indians](http://sioux.org/cheyenne-river-sioux-history.html) engaged in,

> They were a hunting people and traveled frequently in search of their main food source, the sacred American bison or buffalo.

...and the American Buffalo followed migratory feeding patterns.

Comment: *Migrant* has gained quite a lot of baggage recently.  This could be dealt with by providing sufficient  context, but might rule it out in a title or introductory paragraph. Related words in other parts of speech (*migration*, *migrating*) are much less affected.

Comment: +1 for looking up the subject (Wyandotte people) and trying to determine the best word from that context.

Comment: *Migratory community*, maybe, if the subject is village-sized (or larger) groups that move *en masse*.

Answer (score -1):

You can also use Vagabond although the word is used mostly in a negative connotation.

> **Vagabond**
>
> a person who wanders from place to place without a home or job.